# Admob ads only shown once, the first time I run the game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, admob

My problem is this, the Admob ads are shown, but only the first time I run the game, When I exit game and run it again, ads do not show. They will show only if I clear data of the game on android device (clear cache) or if I remove and install the app again.

Note - That applies to Interstitials and video reward ads. (I didn’t test with banner because I don’t need them)

I do not think it is a problem in the script, but some problem of the SDK, however I leave the admanager script for you to take a look

I have tested on another device and the same thing happens.

With test mode ads, It works fine.

```
public void Start()
    {
        //ADMOB
        MobileAds.Initialize(appId);

        //UNITY ADS
        Advertisement.Initialize(gameId, testMode);

        RequestReward();
        RequestInterstitial();
    }

    private void RequestInterstitial()
    {
        // Initialize an InterstitialAd.
        this.interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(interstitialID);
        // Create an empty ad request.

        // Called when the ad is closed.
        this.interstitialAd.OnAdClosed += HandleOnAdClosed;

        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
        // Load the interstitial with the request.
        this.interstitialAd.LoadAd(request);
    }
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm seeing the same thing, especially in EU even though I'm making all the recommended permission calls.